# How to look for 2 text in an element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, element

Here's my code

```
shoe = WebDriverWait(browser, 12000000).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//A[contains(text(),'awling')]"))).click()
```

But I need to look for an element that contains text "awling" and "red" but I don't know how to do it.

Please help thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `or` clause for two different strings. Your xpath modify it as shown below.

```
// A[contains(text(),'awling') or contains(text(),'red')]
```

First test it in browser console and than run it with your code.